# Creating a block to show content in the same group of the current node

Tags: views, 8, group

I would like to create a block that in `node/x` displays the links to all the nodes in the same group as x.
I created a view of Content, a relation of Group but no contextual filter allows me to filter by current node's parent group

Comment: It's still no easily doable and [this is a related issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2821513) I found on the plugin queue

Answer (score 0):

Add contextual filter "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" and make configuration like below

1. Provide default value : Taxonomy term Id from URL
2. Load default filter from node page, that's good for related
   taxonomy blocks

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm using the [**group** module](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) that has more to do with entity relationships than with taxonomy terms

Comment: Okay I will check with group module.